# How to point cpanel to /var/www/html from public_html?

Tags: linux, cpanel

on my Cpanel when i log on to my domain name it is opening the public_html folder by default and also not executing files on that folder it should open `/var/www/html` foler where html file is present

How I can point it to that /var/www/html directory ?

Comment: Official answer: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051373774-How-to-change-the-document-root-for-a-cPanel-account